# How to get the sum of column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I am developing the stored procedure and have a data as below

```
ID Name Value
1  All  0 
2  ABC  10
3  DEF  15
4  GHI  20
```

Now, my requirement is to calculate the sum of all columns except with Name as 'All' and it should show it as a value of 'All'.

So the expected result should be like this.

```
ID Name Value
1  All  45 
2  ABC  10
3  DEF  15
4  GHI  20
```

How do I achieve this using view/stored procedure in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do sum in Sub query and Handle the ALL row with case

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (ID int, Name Varchar(20),Value int)

INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT 1,  'All',  0 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  'ABC',  10
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  'DEF',  15
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,  'GHI',  20
```

Now Select it with case expression

```
SELECT ID
    ,NAME
    ,CASE 
        WHEN NAME = 'All'
            THEN (
                    SELECT SUM(Value)
                    FROM #TAB
                    WHERE NAME <> 'ALL'
                    )
        ELSE VALUE
        END AS VALUE
FROM #TAB
```

And the result will be

```
+----+------+-------+
| ID | NAME | VALUE |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | All  |    45 |
|  2 | ABC  |    10 |
|  3 | DEF  |    15 |
|  4 | GHI  |    20 |
+----+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to help :) @User5590